# Why are some data points in the wrong date bin in plotly time series?

Tags: python, pandas, date, time-series, plotly

I am using python's version of plotly to build time series plots of tweets. But I only want to include tweets in the most recent five days. So I have this code which works as far I can tell (it's a simplified version and not reproducible because I am very sure my dataframe is formatted correctly and pretty sure that the bug lies somewhere in the code below):

```
# Set range to use to limit to recent dates 
min_day = tweet_dataframe['day'].max() - timedelta(days = 5)

reduced_df = tweet_dataframe.loc[tweet_dataframe['date'] > min_day]

# Plot time series
time_series = go.Scatter(
    x = reduced_df['date'],
    y = reduced_df['vader_polarity'],
    name = topic,
    mode = 'markers'
    hoverinfo = 'x+text',
    text = reduced_df['custom_text'],
    )

fig.append_trace(time_series) 
offline_plot.plot(fig, filename = path, auto_open = True)
```

This generates an interactive time series that displays the date and some custom text. After manually checking the hover info, it looks like the data points match what I would expect from the dataframe.

However, using the approach below, without defining a reduced_df, a few of the data points display the wrong hover information or are plotted in the wrong date bin. When I do not include the `> min_day` bit, the plots are fine.

```
time_seres = go.Scatter(
    x = tweet_dataframe['date'].loc[tweet_dataframe['date'] > min_day],
    y = tweet_dataframe['vader_polarity'].loc[tweet_dataframe['day'] > min_day, 
    name = topic,
    mode = 'markers',
    hoverinfo = 'x+text',
    text = tweet_dataframe['custom_text']
    )
```

Has anyone had a similar problem with plotting time series in plotly, or is there an obvious error in my plotly/pandas logic?

Comment: since I have not posted to stackoverflow before, please explain your down vote of the question. It would be very helpful

Comment: It was not me, but because you haven't posted a [mcve] your question will likely be received poorly. You're having an issue, but haven't provided an example that we can run, debug and check, so it's pretty difficult to say if the problem lies within that code chunk, or the processing before, even if you assure us that everything is formatted correctly.

Comment: @ALollz Thanks for the reply! That makes sense but I don't need nor do I want anyone to waste their time trying to reproduce my error; I only need someone to look at what I have and point out if there is an obvious error in pandas or plotly formatting. Is there a way to ask questions like that without getting a down vote instantly?

Comment: *I want anyone to waste their time trying to reproduce my error* That's not how this works. No one interprets code better than a computer. Read the link above, follow its advice, and you'll be asking good questions in no time.

Comment: @PaulH. That makes sense. I agree, but in this case the computer would throw no error in either instance of the code and it would take a lot of time for someone to understand the graphs produced and compare the interactive text in the graphs to actual tweets to see which tweets were not in the proper bin. Anyway, I appreciate your feedback and will try to ask better questions in the future.

Comment: OK, so it wouldn't throw an error. But if you really follow the advice of the article and truly strip your problem down to the *minimal* example needed to recreate the problem, then it won't take a long time to a clearly described issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found my bug. All I needed was to specify the date range in the text argument of plotly like so

```
time_seres = go.Scatter(
    x = tweet_dataframe['date'].loc[tweet_dataframe['date'] > min_day],
    y = tweet_dataframe['vader_polarity'].loc[tweet_dataframe['day'] > min_day], 
    name = topic,
    mode = 'markers',
    hoverinfo = 'x+text',
    text = tweet_dataframe['custom_text'].loc[tweet_dataframe['day'] > min_day]
    )
```